# Conversion from NSString to NSDate doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have to convert this NSString: "12/13/1980" to a NSDate object. 
I use a code like this:

```
NSString *birthday = @"12/13/1980"
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

But the result is this: "1980-12-12 23:00:00 +0000"
Why? I'd like the same format and the same date.
Thank you very much.

Comment: use `nslog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringWithDate:date]);`

Comment: I suppose `dateString`is not equal to `birthday`.

Comment: try to remove the time using [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

Comment: No, the NSString is really "12/13/1980" and I try to use  [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]; but the time is still in the date and there are no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[dateFormat dateFromString:dateString]` method produces an NSDate object which represents a single point in time.

When you NSLog a date object, it is printing a system representation of the NSDate object. I'm assuming your locale is GMT+1 .. so the NSLog prints 12/12/1980 23:00.

If you want to print the date object back, use your formatter to do `[dateFormat stringFromDate:date];`

Comment: i am glad someone had the correct answer... i was gonna start burning downvotes...

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand the 23:00:00 but I still don't Understand the change in date: from 12/13/1980 to 1980/12/12 how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Dont worry about the output of NSDate. it is simply saying that when it was midnight in your locale on 12/13/1980, the time was 11pm the previous day in London. The more important question is that once you have the NSDate object, what do you plan to do with it? Display on screen ? Then use the dateFormat object again.

Comment: @user2136333 it isn't a real change.. your date object is in a different time zone... ie it has no time zone... you have a time zone that gets added in when you NSLog

Comment: @Kal the NSDate will be put in an object "user" and will be part of your attributes. So I'd like to have the same format of the original NSString

Comment: @user2136333 - ok. You either save it as an NSDate into your user attributes and at display time use dateFormat to format it or you convert it into a string ans store it as a string as a part of your user attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The format is dependent on the localisation, there's also the option to set whether the date/time is short, medium or long format - I believe short is what you're looking for:

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];  
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I've tried to add                                             [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; but still don't works, the final format is always the same: "1980-12-12 23:00:00 +0000"

Comment: Are you inspecting the NSDate *date?  NSDate objects will always have a date and time field.

Comment: this would result into the same, as the hour and minute will be set to 0.

Comment: Yes, the hours and minutes would be 0, but only if `[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]; ` is being set.  I don't think the OP is doing so as the log shows 23:00 hours.   I was just informing the OP that the date will always look similar to the above if he's inspecting the NSDate object, rather than converting it to a string as demonstrated in other posts.

Answer (score 1):

It's because a NSDate object has always to have a time and a timezone, so if you don't specify that in your the string you're trying to convert IOS will use your local timezone and then guess the time, wich in this case will be 23:00 in UTC 0

Comment: Ok, can you tell me the code that I have to write? I'd like the date without the time.

Comment: nslog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringWithDate:date]);